# Is the "module;" statement required for c++-20 modules

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have been experimenting and hade realized that on some sites the examples starts with the line:

```cpp
module;
```

to define that the file is a module.

My question is twofold:

- Is the "module;" going to be required for a c++-module
- Is it supposed to be a way of differentiating between module files and non module files (instead of file-extension)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`module;` on its own starts the [global module fragment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules). You can have a module file without that specific form, but you will need the keyword `module` somewhere.

The C++ standard has never mandated particular file extensions, so it would be strange to do so here.

Comment: Not just somewhere—absent a global module fragment, the module declaration must be the very first declaration in the translation unit.

Comment: @DavisHerring absent a global module frament. What does that mean? Do you mean that you have no imports or includes before the "export module" statement?

Comment: @Lasersköld: Exactly: imports go after it, and `#include` goes *in* the global module fragment.

Comment: @DavisHerring So to be clear, you cannot start a module file with "export module x"?

Comment: @Lasersköld: Of course you can (that’s the module declaration, and it’s first), but such a file will generally not `#include` anything, since it would become part *of* the module rather than a dependency of it.

Comment: @DavisHerring Ok, so what what your first comment about? Do you want to clarify that you should not put declarations and such before the module statement or what do you mean? To me it sounds like "putting the keyword module somewhere" should work, and I find it hard to come up with an example for when it will not from your comments...

Comment: @Lasersköld: The answer says “you will need the keyword `module` somewhere”; I was merely pointing out that it’s always either the first or second token in a module unit.  (This is meant to simplify tooling.)